# getting an error in sending a value to RequestParam from JSP file

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have the following code:

```
<c:forEach var="listValue" items="${upcomingMovieslists}">
        div style="border:thin inset #6E6E6E; text-align: justify;> <p margin-left: 1em;">&nbsp;&nbsp;<c:set var="movieName" scope="application" value="${listValue.key}"/><a  href="/myapp/movie/SubmitMovie/" >${listValue.key}</a></p></div>
</c:forEach>
```

and movieName is going to be in ***@RequestParam  String movieName*** in the page that it is going next.

So, When I run this code I am getting an error telling:

```
error:
message Required String parameter 'movieName' is not present

description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
```

Controller method:

My controller class to where the call is going:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/SubmitMovie", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getSearchedMovie(@RequestParam String movieName, ModelMap model)
```

The URL currently is: `/myapp/movie/SubmitMovie/`

It should be `/myapp/movie/SubmitMovie/?movieName=deadpool`
in order to work

I should have /?movieName= to show the results in the next page but where as with the above jsp code I will not get the movieName in String format instead it comes in the form ${movieName} which cannot be accepted to a String present in the RequestParam and hence it throws an error.

I want to know how I can fix it to get the moviename in Stringformat in the URL so that I can populate the results

Thanks

Comment: Can you add the parameters of movie object of which upcomingMovieslists is created

Comment: And please do not ask multiple questions, edit your previous one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36321761/error-in-getting-the-value-from-list-in-jsp-file

Comment: @DevanshuDwivedi: I have deleted that post. I made this new post because I have done some progress with the code and this is the new probem that I am facing

Comment: @DevanshuDwivedi regarding the first one there are not parameters in which upcomingMovieslists is created. That is the start page where I will be gettng the data to a Map and returning to the JSP file which is used to show them in a list form. From there Ia m trying to click the element shown in the list which gives me the above error when I click the element in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a whole lot of code there, so I don't know exactly what you're going for, but you can always add a `required=false` condition to a request parameter, like so:

```
@RequestParam(value = "movieName", required = false) String movieName
```

That should at least clear that error. If the logic in your model *does* require movieName, though, then you're going to need to refactor around that -- i.e., your link would need to look like `href="/myapp/movie/SubmitMovie?movieName='${listValue.key}'"` .

(Note: I'm inferring from your code that `${listValue.key}` is the name of the movie. Whatever variable you want the controller to receive as the `@RequestParam String movieName`, place it after `?movieName=` in the href string, after escaping it with single quotes (see how I did so above.)

If you're still stuck, maybe try showing the controller for the page with that parameter?

Comment: Cool! If it works, please feel free to accept the answer as having helped :) if not, let me know if you have a further issue, I'd be happy to try debugging

Comment: I should have /?movieName= to show the results in the next page but where as with the above jsp code I will not get the movieName in String format instead it comes in the form ${movieName} which cannot be accepted to a String and hence it throws an error. I want to know how I can fix it to get the moviename in the URL so that I can populate the results.

If my message is still not clear then please let me know so that I can correct it accordingly to make it more understanding

Comment: Thanks for providing the controller also, but yes, the issue is in the original block you submitted. Make the following edit: `<a  href="/myapp/movie/SubmitMovie?movieName='${listValue.key}'" >${listValue.key}</a>`

Comment: You were right, you can't just put in `${listValue.key}` nor `${movieName}` into the href query string, as it will just set those as part of the literal string. That's why you need to escape the original string with the `'...'` around the `${...}`. This should do the trick.

Comment: Though I should add, I'm inferring what I see in your original post, about your usage of movieName as a var, then you're going back using listValue.key when you display the name of your href link ... I'm not sure which variable has the name of the movie you want in it, but whatever variable it is, throw it into the href using the " '${yourVariableHere}' " pattern I offered above.

Comment: I got it fixed with the above change that you have mentioned. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Great! Glad to hear it. I would appreciate it if you would accept the answer, if you wouldn't mind taking a second to do so :)